# Automated way to create a confusion matrix in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of this form in Google Sheets:

```
+---------+------------+--------+
| item_id | prediction | actual |
+---------+------------+--------+
|       1 |          1 |      1 |
|       2 |          1 |      1 |
|       3 |          1 |      0 |
|       4 |          0 |      1 |
|       5 |          0 |      0 |
|       6 |          1 |      1 |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

And I'd like to know if there's an automated way to get this kind of summary, with the counts of items that fit the criteria specified in that row/column combination:

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+-------+
|          | prediction=0 | prediction=1 | total |
+----------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| actual=0 |            1 |            1 |     2 |
| actual=1 |            1 |            3 |     4 |
+----------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| total    |            2 |            4 |       |
+----------+--------------+--------------+-------+
```

I've been doing this somewhat manually in Google Sheets by using COUNTIFS, but I'm wondering if there's a built-in way? I tried using pivot tables, but couldn't figure out how to get the calculated fields to show the data I want.

Answer (score 2):

A coworker figured it out - you can get this by creating a pivot table with the correct columns and rows, and setting the value to item_id summarized by COUNTUNIQUE.